# Tablet Screen Media Query multiple screen factors

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi I am targeting my application for various tablets screen. Targeted devices are

- Samsung Tab 1, 2, 3 - 7 inch
- Samsung Tab 4 - 7 and 10 inch
- Nexus 7 2012
- Nexus 7 2013 and later

Used the below media query.

```
/* LANDSCAPE:
Apple iPad
Apple iPad 2
Apple iPad 3 (and 4)
Apple iPad Mini
Archos 80G9
BAUHN AMID-972XS
HP Touchpad
Panasonic Toughpad A1
Acer Iconia Tab A101
Archos 70b (it2)
Arnova 10b G3
BlackBerry PlayBook
Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0
Samsung Galaxy Tab 7
Ainol Novo 7 Elf 2*/

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1024px) and
(device-width:1024px) (orientation : landscape) and
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1) {

}
```

/* Nexus 7 2012 */
/* 1280 x 800 pixels (216 ppi) */

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:602px) and (orientation :
landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.331) and
(-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.332) { }
```

/* Nexus 7 2013
1920 x 1200 pixels (323 ppi) */

```
@media screen
and (min-device-width: 602px)
and (orientation : landscape) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/23){  }
```

/* Media Query for Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10 inch  */

```
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) and (device-width:1280px) and
(max-width:1280px) and (orientation:landscape) and
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1) and (device-aspect-ratio:8/5) {  }
```

And have some general css for the entire app. My Nexus 7 2012, samsung 10 and samsung galaxy 1,2,3 works fine. But the media query for Nexus 7 2013 does't have any effect. In nexus 2013 its not using any of these media query.

Please post me , if anyone came across the similar kind of issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My question to you is why are you specifically targeting certain devices instead of a more fluid responsive web app which will work across devices, is the CSS drastically different for each device?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a viewport in order to make media queries work. A standard meta viewport would be like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```